# Extracting xml data from CLOB in Oracle and Pivoting

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a table that has a CLOB column with the following data:

```
<entry xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Parameters>
            <data>
               <parameter>
                    <id>{1234}</id>
                    <value>1000</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                   <id>{3456}</id>
                   <value>John Doe</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                   <id>{6789}</id>
                    <value>NY</value>
                </parameter>
               </data>              
            </d:Parameters>
        </m:properties>
   </content>
</entry>
```

The ID values are stored in a separate table where {3456} would be «Name » etc.

I need to retrieve data from multiple rows and pivot it so the result is

```
{1234}  {3456}.    {6789}
1000.  John Doe.     NY
1001.  Jane Doe.     DE
1002.  Ivan Riveras. NJ
```

And potentially replace {1234} strings with actual column names from another table such as ID, Name and State

How can I do that with a query?

So far I have

SELECT xmltype(t1.column1).extract(“//data/text()”)
FROM Table1 t1

But how do I break it down further and pivot?

Comment: As I see; yourdata is not in proper XML format. Have you tried using `String functions in select query ?`

Comment: You cannot get dynamic column names without dynamic SQL, because column names are known fot the query processor at the parsing stage.

Comment: @astentx that's fine, as long as I can parse and pivot the data I am good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting the values is fairly straightforward; as you want multiple node values from each XML document you can use XMLTable:

```
select x.code, x.value
from table1 t1
cross join xmltable(
    '/data/parameter'
    passing xmltype(t1.column1)
    columns
      code path 'id',
      value path 'value'
  ) x;
```

which with two sample documents gives:

| CODE | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| {1234} | 1000 |
| {3456} | John Doe |
| {6789} | NY |
| {1234} | 1001 |
| {3456} | Jane Doe |
| {6789} | DE |

You can then pivot those; but really you need a way to link the values together. If your table has a unique key then use that; otherwise you can use the first table's `rowid` as a stand-in:

```
select rowidtochar(t1.rowid), x.code, x.value
from table1 t1
cross join xmltable(
    '/data/parameter'
    passing xmltype(t1.column1)
    columns
      code path 'id',
      value path 'value'
  ) x;
```

Either way, use that value internally to pivot, but don't include it in the final select list:

```
select id, name, state
from (
  select rowidtochar(t1.rowid), x.code, x.value
  from table1 t1
  cross join xmltable(
      '/data/parameter'
      passing xmltype(t1.column1)
      columns
        code path 'id',
        value path 'value'
    ) x
)
pivot (
  max(value)
  for code in ('{1234}' as id, '{3456}' as name, '{6789}' as state)
);
```

| ID | NAME | STATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | John Doe | NY |
| 1001 | Jane Doe | DE |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tiPaC-jm)

I've hard-coded the mapping between ID values and column headings in the `IN()` clause; you said

> And potentially replace {1234} strings with actual column names from another table such as ID, Name and State

but that would requite a dynamic pivot, as @astentx said in a comment.

As a middle-ground, if you know you will have ID/name/state but don't know what the codes are and want to look up the mapping then you could do that before pivoting, with something like:

```
select id, name, state
from (
  select rowidtochar(t1.rowid), t2.label, x.value
  from table1 t1
  cross join xmltable(
      '/data/parameter'
      passing xmltype(t1.column1)
      columns
        code path 'id',
        value path 'value'
    ) x
  join table2 t2 on t2.code = to_number(translate(x.code, 'x{}', 'x'))
)
pivot (
  max(value)
  for label in ('ID' as id, 'Name' as name, 'State' as state)
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/o-mOhSX_)

The inner query now translates the original `id` from the XML to a label from your look-up table, and *that* is then used to pivot.

But if you don't know the label values, or how many rows you will pivot into how many columns, then you're still stuck with a dynamic pivot; or having a reporting too do that for you, perhaps.

---

> Sorry, I did not post the full xml. Just added the rest

Your updated XML has namespaces, so you need to declare those:

```
select id, name, state
from (
  select rowidtochar(t1.rowid), x.code, x.value
  from table1 t1
  cross join xmltable(
      xmlnamespaces(
        default 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom',
        'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' as "d",
        'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata' as "m"
      ),
      '/entry/content/m:properties/d:Parameters/data/parameter'
      passing xmltype(t1.column1)
      columns
        code path 'id',
        value path 'value'
    ) x
)
pivot (
  max(value)
  for code in ('{1234}' as id, '{3456}' as name, '{6789}' as state)
);
```

> does the first parameter of the xmltable need to be the full path or can I use //?

You can still use

```
      '//data/parameter'
```

with the namespaces declared, but I generally prefer to use the full path for clarity.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JaVKl68g)

Comment: the problem is my table column is of type CLOB so this does not work - I am getting inconsistent data type error

Comment: My example has the XML stored as a CLOB, so that shouldn't be a problem. Do both queries error or just the second one - if the second, is what I've called `label` also a a CLOB, which would seem odd?

Comment: does the first parameter of the `xmltable` need to be the full path or can I use `//`? Sorry, I did not post the full xml. Just added the rest

Comment: You can use `//` - with your sample [it gets the same result](https://dbfiddle.uk/CEYWcixw) with `//parameter`.

Comment: I tried select x.code, x.value
from table1 t1
cross join xmltable(
    '//data/parameter'
    passing xmltype(t1.column1)
    columns
      code path 'id',
      value path 'value'
  ) x;  and it did not return anything. I added the tags to the original xml

Comment: @CodingDuchess - your updated XML has namespaces, which is important. I've added how to declare those.